CubeJS Error: Unsupported REPLACE() function in SQL Query: "Error during rewrite: Can't detect Cube query"
I’m trying to run a simple SQL query in CubeJS, but the REPLACE() function is causing an error.
Here’s my query:
SELECT 
    REPLACE(my_column, 'work', '') AS a
FROM 
    my_table

Without the REPLACE function, it works perfectly in CubeJS, but with it, I get this error:
Error during rewrite: Can't detect Cube query and it may be not supported yet.
Please check logs for additional information.
Does anyone have a workaround or hint to get this working?
Logs:
│ 2024-11-08 14:13:52,326 DEBUG [cubesql::compile::rewrite::rewriter] Iterations: [Iteration { egraph_nodes: 43, egraph_classes: 43, applied: {"cube-scan": 1, "limi │
│ 2024-11-08 14:13:52,327 DEBUG [cubesql::compile::rewrite::rewriter] Best: RecExpr { nodes: [ProjectionSplit(ProjectionSplit(false)), ProjectionAlias(ProjectionAli │
│ 2024-11-08 14:13:52,330 ERROR [cubesql::compile] It may be this query is not supported yet. Please post an issue on GitHub https://github.com/cube-js/cube.js/issu │
│ 2024-11-08 14:13:52,331 TRACE [cubesql::sql::postgres::shim] disabled backtrace                                                                                    │
│ Cube SQL Error: undefined                                                                                                                                          │
│ --                                                                                                                                                                 │
│ "SELECT REPLACE(report_status, 'D', '') AS toto FROM public.fac_report WHERE report_created_at >= '2024-11-07 00:00:00' AND report_type_name = 'Document Report' L │
│ --                                                                                                                                                                 │
│ {                                                                                                                                                                  │
│   "protocol": "postgres",                                                                                                                                          │
│   "apiType": "sql",                                                                                                                                                │
│   "sanitizedQuery": "SELECT REPLACE(report_status, 'D', '') AS toto FROM public.fac_report WHERE report_created_at >= '[REPLACED]' AND report_type_name = '[REPLAC │
│   "appName": "NULL"                                                                                                                                                │
│ }                                                                                                                                                                  │
│ Error during rewrite: Can't detect Cube query and it may be not supported yet. Please check logs for additional information.                                       │
│ 2024-11-08 14:13:52,366 DEBUG [cubesql::sql::postgres::shim] Query: ROLLBACK                                                                                       │
│ 2024-11-08 14:13:52,366 TRACE [cubejs_native::transport] [transport] Meta ->                                                                                       │
│ 2024-11-08 14:13:52,379 TRACE [cubejs_native::transport] [transport] Meta <- <hidden>                                                                              │
│ 2024-11-08 14:13:52,379 DEBUG [cubesql::compile::parser] Parsing SQL: ROLLBACK                                                                                     │
│ 2024-11-08 14:13:52,381 TRACE [cubesql::sql::postgres::service] [pg] Removing connection 79  


cubesql Are you sure this is PostgreSQL?
